# Azure CLI - Azure Devops - Release pipline - Variable updates

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cli, dynamics-365

For the dynamics 365 hotfix build and release, I have created a build pipeline variable to get the patch name.

Currently, I am checking to pass the variable in the pipeline to release and use it to deploy in the different instances, but not sure how to do that.  All the blogs and answers are related to classic pipelines and related to Rest.

I thought of using Azure CLI script to update the release pipeline variable as a build pipeline step - as a workaround.

az pipelines variable list --org $orgname --project $projectname --pipeline-name $pipelinename

The above script works perfectly fine and lists the variables in the BUILD pipeline but it is not retrieving the release pipeline variables and the below error is shown.

ERROR: There were no build definitions matching the name "WM.CRM.Rls.DeploySITHotfix" in the project "Mustaque-ADO".

can you please advise if this is intended to work only with Build variables and not the Release variables ?

Is there a way I can pass via the ADO pipelines the dynamics build variable to the release and use it in the task steps?

[image]

Comment: I think you would need to output the build variable as a build artifact. Build artifacts are used as input by release pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Cli `az pipelines variable list` only works for build/yaml  pipeline but not for classsic release pipeline.

> Currently, I am checking to pass the variable in the pipeline to release and use it to deploy in the different instances, but not sure how to do that.

You can use rest api to get release definition([Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)) and then update variable([Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)).

Please grant Project Collection Build Service (xxx) account the edit release pipeline permission. (Select the release pipeline --> ... --> Security --> Edit release definition set to Allow)
[image]

Sample as below:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- script: echo $(var1)         # This is variable in build pipeline.

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{yourorg}/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/Release/definitions/3?api-version=5.0"
      Write-Host "URL: $url"
      $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
          Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
      }
      Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
      # Update an existing variable named var3 to its new value $(var1)
      $pipeline.variables.var3.value = "$(var1)"
      ####****************** update the modified object **************************
      $json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
      $updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
      write-host "==========================================================" 
      Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'var3' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.var3.value
      write-host "=========================================================="
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Pipeline result:
[image]

Check for release pipeline value:
[image]

To directly edit on local PS:

```
Param(
   [string]$org = "yourorgname",
   [string]$projectName = "yourprojectname",
   [string]$releasedefinitionid = "3",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "yourPAT", 
   [string]$buildvar = "testvar2"
)
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))


$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$org/$projectName/_apis/Release/definitions/$releasedefinitionid"+"?api-version=5.0"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
  Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
# Update an existing variable named var3 to its new value $buildvar
$pipeline.variables.var3.value = $buildvar
####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
write-host "==========================================================" 
Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'var3' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.var3.value
write-host "=========================================================="
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I use this directly as a Powershell ?  I never worked in YAML and hence using this in PS gives the below error for the line

Comment: @MustaqueAli, the rest api works but some change needed for the script if you directly run on local PS.
1. Make sure you have correct url set(org, project, releasedefinitionid). 
2. Use PAT(personal access token) instead of SYSTEM_TOKEN.

I edit the reply with sample code. please check.

Comment: Perfectly Worked. Thank you @Wade.

Comment: Glad to know it helps! @MustaqueAli